# Typescript: generating an interface object from another interface, using keyof, but renaming the key using a string concatenation

Tags: typescript

Usecase: I have a bunch of select boxes and a bunch of select options populating the box.

These are the types I have for this:

```
type Option<T = any> = {
    value: T
    // reserve for option
    [prop: string]: any
}

export type OptionType<T = any> = Option<T>

interface SelectBox {
    affiliate_id: number
    campaign_id: string
    username: number | string | undefined
}

interface SelectBoxOptions {
    affiliate_id_options: OptionType<number>[]
    campaign_id_options: OptionType<string>[]
    username_options: OptionType<number | string | undefined>[]
}
```

Is there a way I can automate the `SelectBoxOptions` type, since it follows a perdictable pattern?

I tried to use this myself:

```
export type SelectBoxOptions<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as `${K}_options`]: OptionType<T[K]>[]
}
```

Example use case:

```
//
//     interface NumberFilter {
//         affiliate_id: number
//         campaign_id: string
//     }
//
//     SelectBoxOptions<NumberFilter> == {
//         affiliate_id_options: OptionType<number>[]
//         campaign_id_options: OptionType<string>[]
//     }
//
```

But I get this error from `tsc`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrHRv.png

```
app/javascript/app/services/FilterService.ts:51:25 - error TS2322: Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.
  Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.
    Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.
      Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.

51     [K in keyof T as `${K}_options`]: OptionType<T[K]>[]
```

I can't figure out why this generic type is erroring? It generates the right output on hover in VSCode when I use it...

Not to get an error on "K" in `${K}_options`

Comment: You can't stringify symbols*. Filter them out by intersecting `keyof T` with `string | number` (or just `string`).

Comment: @kelsny how would you do the intersecting? I tried doing as but got some errors

Comment: Use `&`, parentheses needed if you intersect with a union

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "stringify" symbols, so by extension, you can't include them in template literal types.

Intersect `keyof T` with `string` to filter out any other types (namely `number` and `symbol` in this case):

```
type Option<T = any> = {
  value: T;
  // reserve for option
  [prop: string]: any;
};

export type OptionType<T = any> = Option<T>;

interface SelectBox {
  affiliate_id: number;
  campaign_id: string;
  username: number | string | undefined;
}

export type SelectBoxOptions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as `${K}_options`]: OptionType<T[K]>[];
};

interface NumberFilter {
  affiliate_id: number;
  campaign_id: string;
}

type X = SelectBoxOptions<NumberFilter>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAFSgXigQxRAD4coBvAWACgooA3PAGwFcIAuKDAbmtoHo+UAE4QAzhCF1oAMyRCoSeMhS8oAbTBDFHUcCEIUAcwC6HAiB5UAvpeoQAHmDnAooSLCWoM4CJlLmSXDhEVEwiWyoDYAlpPABjaABlCEYIOOAAISR7clU8aWkERgQ8aIB9BAATDhRmAFsAIwlLWji8OrA8BEMUCuqoXX0jFqhmcSEUdvYoWsaJKAAfAb0DQ0XRlEqIQpQISssrajtHZ1cfKGTU9Kz7YOVRMNJKGnUAaSgDKABrCBAkaU4UAAZMshms8KIoAADAAkZFeVjKihCKFEUNMHhR3kgmDUr2MRDUxgOESiMXi0AAcvUmkIAGJFaLyZ60fKFYqlCB9Go05qqNodLo9bmg1YHI5UNzQAAapEuaUy2TuqAe1Lm9MZEnC1CAA)

---

Numbers do not have to be included as if `T` is a tuple, the keys will be given as strings; `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, and so on. That is why intersecting with only `string` is sufficient.